# How to save each line of the string into a new string in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am reading the data file and it looks like this

```
ie=1
is=5
```

I have imported the file and saved its content to input variable which is a string.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fileP = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int line = 0;
    char input[10];  

    if (fileP == NULL){
       perror("ERROR");
    }

    while (fgets(input,10,fileP)){
        line++;

    printf("%s",input);
    }
    // input has ie=1 and is=5.
    // Seperate the two lines

    //int length = 3;
      //  printf("\n%*.*s", length, length, "is=1");

    //char *isString = strtok(input, ' ');
       // printf("%s\n", isString);

    //char *myStr1 = isString;
    //int is = atoi(&myStr1[3]);
       // printf("%i\n", is);

    char *ieString = strtok(input, " ");
    //printf("%s\n", ieString);

    char *myStr2 = ieString;
    int ie = atoi(&myStr2[3]);
    printf("\n%i", ie);

    fclose(fileP);
    return 0;

}
```

How do I separate the two lines and save it in a different string?
Currently I'm having trouble extracting the first line from the data.

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Provide a MVCE.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you tried. StackOverflow is for answering questions on fixing programming problems you encountered while programming. This question broadly asks for help with achieving a programming goal - if not for having that goal achieved by others. Please understand that those things are not the same. If you show the code you describe, it might be enough to get answers which point out suitable functions from the available libraries.

Comment: I apologize for the un-formatted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that for each line the key and the corresponding value should be extracted.

It makes sense that the key-value pair is represented in a struct.

In a loop this struct can be filled and in another loop the values can be output.

If one takes your code and adjust it accordingly, it could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_KEY 5
#define MAX_LINES 5
#define MAX_INPUT 10

struct key_value {
    char key[MAX_KEY];
    int value;
};

int main() {

    FILE *fileP = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    char input[MAX_INPUT];
    struct key_value dict[MAX_LINES];

    if (fileP == NULL) {
        perror("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }

    int line = 0;
    while (fgets(input, MAX_INPUT, fileP)) {
        char *delimiter = strchr(input, '=');
        if(delimiter) {
            snprintf(dict[line].key, delimiter - input + 1, "%s", input);
            dict[line].key[delimiter - input] = '\0';
            dict[line].value = atoi(delimiter + 1);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "delimiter = not found in line %d\n", line);
            exit(1);
        }
        if(line == MAX_LINES) {
            fprintf(stderr, "too many input lines");
            exit(1);
        }
        line++;
    }
    fclose(fileP);

    for(int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        printf("key:%s value:%d\n", dict[i].key, dict[i].value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

The output to the debug console would then look like this:

```
key:ie value:1
key:is value:5
```

**More Robust Solution**

It is worth mentioning that atoi does not report any conversion errors.

Therefore `man atoi` advises:

> The strtol() and strtol_l() functions are recommended instead of atoi() and atoi_l() functions, especially in new code.